# Fabric JS drawing becomes non responsive

Tags: javascript, memory-management, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have been developing a free hand drawing app using Fabric JS, and some custom brush classes on top of it. However, when I tested it on an iPad now, certain brushes specially spray paint for example become super heavy and almost non-responsive after only 4-5 strokes.

Irrespective of my project's code, the problem can be observed by opening the official demo in an iPad's Safari: [Fabric JS Official Demo](http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing/)

I am extremely pleased with the smooth behaviour of other brushes and patterns. However, this problem must be fixed somehow before I can even think of releasing the app as this has a very bad effect on the usability.

Does this have something to do with memory management or the spray creating too many object instances ? Can I make some changes to make this at least somewhat faster ?

Another side note is that I have read in kangax (the official Fabric JS developer)'s notes somewhere that Fabric has a concept of static canvases if interaction is not needed. I am not sure if this is about not using free drawing mode (drag-drop mode etc.) but I just wanted to mention here that I do not need to exit from drawing mode at all. Please let me know what would be a good approach to tackle this issue, specially for iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

As shown here : https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Optimizing-performance

You can remove selection listeners with *object.selectable=false* & also remove selection *canvas.selection = false* , that will increase performance.

Also, you could try *canvas.renderOnAddRemove=false* as your spray is a set of many objects.

Let us know if it's worth.

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't really help. I have thoroughly attempted all the ideas mentioned in that Optimizing Performance page. :(

Comment: Oh, my bad ... So, actually, if you want to stay with fabric you will have to optimize the lib itself. What you could do is to store each object with JSON after finishing drawing and repaint the background of the canvas with the current objects (as if all of what you are painting was just an image) and hide the objects. Basic caching, but not basic coding.